# Retrieve data from JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

When I click on a link in jspA, it will redirect to jspB with query string *src*. The message for *src* will be displayed in jspB without problem. However, why I tried to click on the submit, I am unable to retrieve the value of *src* in my servlet page. Is there a way for me to retrieve the value of *src* in servlet? Thanks.

Inside my jspB page:

```
<img src="<%= request.getParameter("src") %>" />
<table>     
    <form name="frmTest" action="test" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="sub" name="sub" />
    </form>
</table>
```

Inside my Servlet test:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException{

    String imgUrl = req.getParameter("src");
```

I am retrieving null value from the *imrUrl*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you submit an html `form`, only the `input` and `select` elements are sent as parameters. You don't have any that have a `name` attribute set to `src`.

You can use a hidden `input`

```
<form name="frmTest" action="test" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="sub" name="sub" />
    <input type="hidden" name="src" value="<%= request.getParameter("src") %>" />
</form>
```

[It is generally discouraged to use scriptlets.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) Read up on JSTL and EL and use those technologies instead.

Comment: Thanks and the hidden field solved my issue. I have changed to ${param.src} too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean Submit from jspB? If so, you need to store the src value in a hidden field in the form so it is available when the servlet is called on submit. Something like the following

```
<form name="frmTest" action="test" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" value="<%= request.getParameter("src") %>" name="src" />
    <input type="submit" value="sub" name="sub" />
</form>
```

PS You should avoid using scriptlet (i.e. the code between <% and %>) and instead use jsp expression language